# How is the 'new' action redirected to 'create' in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, redirect, routes

In Rails I can automatically create a set of routes for CRUD actions using `resources` in the routes file.

This creates `index`, `new`, `create`, `edit`, `show`, `update` and destroy routes.

I understand the general flow of how these routes work and usually when a route is called a model object is created according to the parameters passed into the corresponding action and the corresponding view is created or the client is redirected to another specified action.

Both the `new` and `edit` views can use the same `_form` partial to update the model object in their respective actions. However I am struggling to understand how the client is redirected to another action afterwards.

For example in the `new` action the client is redirected to the `create` action and the model object that was updated in `new` is passed to `create` as a parameter. I don’t understand how this is happening since no redirect is specified and I cannot see how the model object is turned into a parameter.

```
def new
    @article = Article.new
end

def create
    @article = Article.create(article_params)

    redirect_to(article_path(@article.id))
end
```

_form Partial:

```
<%= form_for(@article) do |f| %>
    <ul>
        <% @article.errors.full_messages.each do |error| %>
        <li><%= error %></li>
            <% end %>
        </ul>
    <p>
        <%= f.label( :title ) %><br>
        <%= f.text_field( :title ) %>
    </p>

    <p>
        <%= f.label( :body ) %><br>
        <%= f.text_area( :body ) %>
    </p>

    <p>
        <%= f.submit %>
    </p>

    <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**OOP**

The bottom line answer to your question is that Rails is [**object orientated**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) (by virtue of being built on top of Ruby). This is *very* important, as it means *everything* inside Rails *should* be based around objects:

[image]

This leads me to the routes - the [`resourceful`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default) nature of Rails' routes is down to the same idea, that you need to work with *objects* in your application - hence the `resources` directive providing 7 key actions to manipulate those objects

To fully understand Rails, you really need to look into how it works with objects, specifically how they interact with each other

---

**Redirect**

To answer your question regarding the `redirect`, the simple answer is that **Rails doesn't "redirect" to any action specifically**

Remember, **Rails is [stateless](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateless_protocol)** - it does not persist data through requests - it *only* has the data which you either initialize at the time, or have sent it

What you're confused about is how some of the Rails actions *seem* to be sending your requests to the appropriate "request" action. The answer to this lies in the helpers / methods you use, specifically **form_for**

---

[**form_for**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html)

**form_for** builds forms from their ActiveRecord objects.

Therefore, if you perform the following:

```
#app/controllers/your_controller.rb
Class YourController < ActiveRecord::Base
   def new
      @model = Model.new
   end
end
```

This will give Rails the knowledge that it's loading a `new` object, and therefore will use the `form_for` method to send the request to the *create* action

If you used `form_tag`, you would not get a redirect to the `create` action -- that's the magic of Rails -- it's been built to accommodate objects

Comment: Thank you this was very helpful, so is it part of the rails naming convention that any form_for that references an initialised object will always redirect to 'create' and any object with existing values will redirect to 'update'? So there must always be a 'create' and an 'update' action by convention?

Comment: Yep you're totally right! You must note you only need to use the `create` and `update` actions if you want to -- they don't need to be there all the time, but if using the likes of `form_for`, they *do* need to be present

Comment: I have just encountered a form_for that takes two objects in an array as an argument. How does the routing work for such a case?

Comment: It's just to account for [nested routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources)

Comment: Thanks, the current example I am looking at is of an article and its comments. So when giving the object to assign the form_for values to I also give the object that it is belongs_to so that the correct key_value can be assigned automatically. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

when you hit your new action in routes by `/articles/new`. *It render your form and if you inspect that form you'll see the html generated by your form_for is like this*

```
<%= form_for @article, html: {class: "nifty_form"} do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>
  <%= f.text_area :body, size: "60x12" %>
  <%= f.submit "Create" %>
<% end %>
```

and its HTML would be

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/articles/create" method="post"  class="nifty_form">
  <input id="article_title" name="article[title]" type="text" />
  <textarea id="article_body" name="article[body]" cols="60" rows="12"></textarea>
  <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Create" />
</form>
```

**So when you hit your submit button your form takes you to create method of article with form parameters**

***Same form in edit action***

when you hit your edit action `articles/edit/1`. If you look at your edit action it would have

```
def edit
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
end
```

**So this renders your form with Article which has id 1**

And the same form will have html which will look like this

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/articles/1/update" method="patch"  class="nifty_form">
  <input id="article_title" name="article[title]" type="text" />
  <textarea id="article_body" name="article[body]" cols="60" rows="12"></textarea>
  <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Update" />
</form>
```

**Notice your action is changed in html** because *in your edit action you have initialized @article and your form generates url according to your initialized variable*

Comment: Thanks, that make sense. The only thing I am still confused about is since I am using the same form partial for both 'new' and 'edit' actions how does the form_for helper know which action to send the request to? Because I didnt specify these. When the form is rendered in the 'new' action it sends the request to 'create' but in the 'edit' it sends to 'update', how does it know?

Comment: @Cu1ture as i explained in my answer in new action you have `@article = Article.new` and in edit you have `@article = Article.find(params[:id])` and in your form_for helper you use @article so depending on it's value rails generates corresponding urls for you

Comment: So if I have an initialized Article object with no values the form_for sends a request to the 'create' action but if it has values it sends it to the 'update' action?

Comment: @Cu1ture Exactly! For your edit action your article would have something like id: 2, title: xyz and for new action it would be id: nil, title: nil so rails check for @article and create forms action for you. For details checkout [**`polymorphic urls`**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.1.1/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes.html)

Comment: Thanks, I think im starting to get the hang of this. Just to clarify is the action that is called such as 'Create' the action withing the controller that corresponds to the location where the view is rendered or where the partial file is located? For example I am creating a comment partial that is located in /comments/ but is rendered in /articles/show. Would the action called be comments#create or articles#create?

Comment: @Cu1ture in rails each action by default renders its partial(unless you have specified something else) so if you are in article controllers new action it will show you its new.html.erb so your forms action will also point to that controllers create method

Answer (score 1):

Well, it does not use redirect. It directs you to the exact method with the html form action.

To clarify it:

When you are in "/articles/new". Rails will dispatch you to Controller#new action.

And, if the _form partial is implemented with Form Helpers by using `form_for`

```
<%= form_for @article do |f| %>
<% end %>
```

It will generate html form, like so:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/article" method="post">
</form>
```

As you can see, the form action attribute is `"/article"` which is mapped to your CRUD actions in the resource.

Then, after you click submit button in the form, the data in the form will be sent to `create` action as specified in the form tag action attribute.

And the exact same partial _form (form_for) code we have used, can also be used to edit an Article. If @article record is already existed in the table and the form_for will yield this html form instead:

```
<form action="/article/1" class="edit_article" id="edit_person_1" method="post">
</form>
```

And, you can notice that action attribute now will direct you to `update` action in the CRUD.

Therefore, `form_for` reflects knowledge about the resource it deals with or Record Identification like Rails document said (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#2.3)

Hope this helps you understand it :)

Comment: Thhis makes sense to me except that I have not specified an action in my form_for form partial. I will add my _form partial to my question to clarify

Comment: @Cu1ture I just updated my answer to describe how `form_for` magic works.

Comment: rails form helper will not generate action "/articles/create"

Comment: @SergioTulentsev oh, sorry that was from previous example with `form_for`and :url => {:action => 'create'}. now it's changed.