# Ruby on rails, path after Sending a post form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a form on /contact/new, and when I click a Send, but user did not fill some text_field after verification on server (if @contact.valid?), user is being redirected to /contact/.

I have a navigation bar, and then it fails in highlighting.

```
<% if current_page?(new_contact_path) %>
    <li class="hover-mouse active-menu"><%= link_to "Contact", new_contact_path%></li>
<% else %>
    <li class="hover-mouse"><%= link_to "Contact", new_contact_path%></li>
<% end %>
```

Does somebody knows how to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*That's because when you hit submit button of your form, it takes you to the create action and since your haven't filled your form it simply renders back your form **but you are still on the create method and hence your condition fails*** For details you should checkout [`this answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25216738/how-is-the-new-action-redirected-to-create-in-rails/25216792#25216792)

**Fix**

*You can't use current_page? helper because **your create method and index have same path helpers(only http verb changes)** so if you'll use contacts_path in your current_page it'll show up active class in index action* also so you should use rails [`action_name`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#routing-parameters) helper **will check for your action name and if it's new action or create action** then it will apply active class on your li

```
<% if action_name == "new" || action_name == "create" %>
  <li class="hover-mouse active-menu"><%= link_to "Contact", new_contact_path%></li>
<% else %>
  <li class="hover-mouse"><%= link_to "Contact", new_contact_path%></li>
<% end %>
```